# Unlinked gantt group

Tags: pgfgantt, charts

I created a Gantt chart contains some ganttgroups indicates the phases.  However these ganttgroups get linked with the tasks which I don't want (like the first figure I want it to be like the red arrows).

I tried to link the object before with the object after the ganttgroups but that didn't workout with me (like the second figure when I tried to link object 3 with 5).

Any solutions for this?!

[image: First figure]

[image: Second Figure]

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid
]{0}{17}
\gantttitle{Weeks}{18} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[title left shift=1,title right shift=1]{1}{16}{day}
 \\[grid]

\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{5} \\
\ganttbar{System Analysis}{1}{3} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Design}{4}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System Architecture}{5} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{6}{12} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Implementation}{6}{8} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Benchmarks Implementation}{9}{12} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System and Benchmarks code}{12} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{13} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Evaluation}{13}{13} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Evaluation Results}{13} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{16} \\
\ganttbar{Documentation}{13}{16}\ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{16} 

\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink{elem3}{elem5}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem7}
\ganttlink{elem7}{elem8}
\ganttlink{elem8}{elem9}
\ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}
\ganttlink{elem10}{elem11}
\ganttlink{elem11}{elem12}
\ganttlink{elem12}{elem13}

\end{ganttchart}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to play around with the parameters of the link, namely `link bulge` and `link mid`. They allow you to specify the bulging and the position of the vertical link. See `pgfgantt` documentation for further information, page 38.

Anyway, code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
       \begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid
    ]{0}{17}
    \gantttitle{Weeks}{18} \\
    \gantttitlecalendar*[title left shift=1,title right shift=1]{1}{16}{day}
     \\[grid]

    \ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{5} \\
    \ganttbar{System Analysis}{1}{3} \\
    \ganttlinkedbar{System Design}{4}{5} \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{System Architecture}{5} \ganttnewline

    \ganttgroup{Phase 3}{6}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{System Implementation}{6}{8} \ganttnewline
    \ganttlinkedbar{Benchmarks Implementation}{9}{12} \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{System and Benchmarks code}{12} \ganttnewline

    \ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{13} \\
    \ganttbar{System Evaluation}{13}{13} \ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Evaluation Results}{13} \ganttnewline

    \ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{16} \\
    \ganttbar{Documentation}{13}{16}\ganttnewline
    \ganttmilestone{Milestone}{16} 

    \ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
    \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
    \ganttlink[link bulge=1,link mid=0.3]{elem3}{elem5}
    \ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
    \ganttlink{elem6}{elem7}

    \ganttlink[link bulge=1,link mid=0.3]{elem7}{elem9}
    \ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}

    \ganttlink[link bulge=1,link mid=0.3]{elem10}{elem12}
    \ganttlink{elem12}{elem13}

    \end{ganttchart}\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**EDIT**

Since in a comment the user refines his request I report here  the new code. In order to have the first item of the group not linking to the group itself, it suffices to replace the `\ganttlinkedbar` with `\ganttbar`. I've done it in the following line:

```
 \ganttbar{System Implementation}{6}{8} \ganttnewline
```

the new code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
vgrid
]{0}{17}
\gantttitle{Weeks}{18} \\
\gantttitlecalendar*[title left shift=1,title right shift=1]{1}{16}{day}
 \\[grid]

\ganttgroup{Phase 1}{1}{5} \\
\ganttbar{System Analysis}{1}{3} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Design}{4}{5} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System Architecture}{5} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 3}{6}{12} \\
\ganttbar{System Implementation}{6}{8} \ganttnewline
\ganttlinkedbar{Benchmarks Implementation}{9}{12} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{System and Benchmarks code}{12} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{13} \\
\ganttlinkedbar{System Evaluation}{13}{13} \ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Evaluation Results}{13} \ganttnewline

\ganttgroup{Phase 4}{13}{16} \\
\ganttbar{Documentation}{13}{16}\ganttnewline
\ganttmilestone{Milestone}{16} 

\ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
\ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
\ganttlink[link bulge=2,link mid=0.3]{elem3}{elem5}
\ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
\ganttlink{elem6}{elem7}
\ganttlink{elem7}{elem8}
\ganttlink{elem8}{elem9}
\ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}
\ganttlink{elem10}{elem11}
\ganttlink{elem11}{elem12}
\ganttlink{elem12}{elem13}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Moriambar for you answer, actually the result I want is like what you did except the arrow from the link between the Gantt groups and next elements.  [https://www.4shared.com/photo/7lcXLXYvei/Ryfvt.html# ]

Comment: @F505 I removed the link as you requested.